# Image Button has to be press twice to popup a map

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I am having a problem with image button, I have to press twice to view the map. Below is my script. If you have suggestion I would be glad and appreciate your help

```
Protected Sub ImageButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton4.Click

    Dim txturl1 As String = "https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + txtsrcNo.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcStName.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcCity.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcCountry.Text.Trim
    ImageButton4.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + txturl1 + "',null,'height=600, width=600,status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ');")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you press your `ImageButton` you only add the `onclick` client event that fires the next time you click the button.

You can solve this problem client-side moving `Attributes.Add` in the `Page_init` event and using `javascript` to collect every parameters used to query google maps at runtime.

But I think it is easier to put your `ImageButton` in an `UpdatePanel` and use `ScriptManager` to solve this problem server-side:

```
Dim strurl1 As String = "https://www.google.com/maps?q=" + txtsrcNo.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcStName.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcCity.Text.Trim + ",+" + txtSrcCountry.Text.Trim
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "openNewPage", "window.open('" + strurl1 + "',null,'height=600, width=600,status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ');", True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting the `onclick` code when you press the button.

Any code specified in `onclick`, runs on the client side (browser) when the user clicks on the button. You have to set your `onclick` code from the server side, (like you are doing), but you have to set it before someone presses the button.

Right now, the 1st time you press it, you set the `onclick` code, the 2nd time you press it, the `onclick` code runs and in the client side (browser).

Move your line:

```
ImageButton4.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + txturl1 + "',null,'height=600, width=600,status= no, resizable= yes, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no ');")
```

To form_load or something equivalent, in order to set the `onclick` code before the button is pressed.